# Layout in MVC leaves blank space at the top of the page

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, layout

Hello everyone i hope someone can help me I have a small problem but dont know how to fix it I have checked line by line and idd some changes but still cant fix it, i have the following code for a Layout in MVC:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - Mi aplicación ASP.NET</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    <!-- Tell the browser to be responsive to screen width -->
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">


    <script src="~Scripts/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.7 -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!-- Ionicons -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/bower_components/Ionicons/css/ionicons.min.css">
    <!-- Theme style -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css">
    <!-- AdminLTE Skins. Choose a skin from the css/skins
         folder instead of downloading all of them to reduce the load. -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/dist/css/skins/_all-skins.min.css">
    <!-- Morris chart -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/bower_components/morris.js/morris.css">
    <!-- jvectormap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/bower_components/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap.css">
    <!-- Date Picker -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/bower_components/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css">
    <!-- Daterange picker -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/bower_components/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css">
    <!-- bootstrap wysihtml5 - text editor -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/plugins/bootstrap-wysihtml5/bootstrap3-wysihtml5.min.css">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <!-- Google Font -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,600,700,300italic,400italic,600italic">
</head>
<body id="elementoboy" runat="server" class="hold-transition skin-blue sidebar-mini">
    <div class="wrapper">

        <header class="main-header">
            <!-- Logo -->
            <a href="~/index2.html" class="logo">
                <!-- mini logo for sidebar mini 50x50 pixels -->
                <span class="logo-mini"><b></b></span>
                <!-- logo for regular state and mobile devices -->
                <span class="logo-lg"><b>Hola</b>Staff</span>
            </a>
            <!-- Header Navbar: style can be found in header.less -->
            <nav class="navbar navbar-static-top">
                <!-- Sidebar toggle button-->
                <a href="#" class="sidebar-toggle" data-toggle="push-menu" role="button">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                </a>

                <div class="navbar-custom-menu">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <!-- User Account: style can be found in dropdown.less -->
                        <li class="dropdown user user-menu">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                <img src="~/dist/img/holastaffpicture.jpg" class="user-image" alt="User Image">
                                <span class="hidden-xs"><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblnombreususario2"></asp:Label></span>

                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <!-- User image -->
                                <li class="user-header">
                                    <img src="~/dist/img/holastaffpicture.jpg" class="img-circle" alt="User Image">

                                    <p>
                                    <p><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblnombreusuario3"></asp:Label></p>

                                    </p>
                                </li>
                                <!-- Menu Body -->

                                    <li class="user-body">


                                        <div class="row">

                                            <div class="col-xs-15 text-center">

                                                <button type="button" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("CerrarSession", "Home")'"/>
                                                </div>


                                        </div>

                                        <!-- /.row -->
                                    </li>


                                <!-- Menu Footer-->

                                <li class="user-footer">

                                    <div class="pull-left">





                                    </div>


                                </li>



                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <!-- Control Sidebar Toggle Button -->
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <!-- Left side column. contains the logo and sidebar -->
        <aside class="main-sidebar">
            <!-- sidebar: style can be found in sidebar.less -->
            <section class="sidebar">
                <!-- Sidebar user panel -->
                <div class="user-panel" style="height:auto">
                    <div class="pull-left image">
                        <img style="width:auto" src="~/dist/img/holastaffpicture.jpg" class="img-circle" alt="User Image">
                    </div>
                    <div class="pull-left info">

                        <p><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblnombreusuario"></asp:Label></p>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle text-success"></i> Online</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- search form -->
                <!-- /.search form -->
                <!-- sidebar menu: : style can be found in sidebar.less -->

                <ul class="sidebar-menu" data-widget="tree">
                    <li><a href="/Home/Login"><i class="fa fa-address-card"></i> <span>LoginAdministradores</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Home/GoToVistaEmpleador"><i class="fa fa-institution"></i> <span>Reporte Empleador</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Home/GoToVistaCandidato"><i class="fa fa-child"></i> <span>Reporte Candidato</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Home/GoToVistaVacantes"><i class="fa fa-bullhorn"></i> <span>Reporte Vacantes</span></a></li>
                    <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-info" style="width:100px" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("CerrarSession", "Home")'" />Cerrar Sesion</li>




                </ul>
            </section>
            <!-- /.sidebar -->
        </aside>

        <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
            <section class="content-header">
                <h1>
                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
                    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                </h1>
            </section>

            <!-- Main content -->
            <section class="content">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="CPH1" runat="server">

                            <div class="container body-content">
                                @RenderBody()
                                <hr />
                                <footer>
                                    <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - Reporting HolaStaff</p>
                                </footer>
                            </div>



                        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </section>
            <!-- /.content -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.content-wrapper -->
        <footer class="main-footer">
            <div class="pull-right hidden-xs">
                <b>Version</b> 2.4.0
            </div>
            <strong>Copyright &copy;<a href="https://holastaff.mx">HolaStaff</a>.</strong> All rights
            reserved.
        </footer>

        <!-- Control Sidebar -->
        <!-- /.control-sidebar -->
        <!-- Add the sidebar's background. This div must be placed
             immediately after the control sidebar -->
        <div class="control-sidebar-bg"></div>
    </div>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
    <!-- ./wrapper -->
    <!-- jQuery 3 -->
    <script src="~/Content/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- jQuery UI 1.11.4 -->
    <script src="~/Content/bower_components/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Resolve conflict in jQuery UI tooltip with Bootstrap tooltip -->
    <script>
        $.widget.bridge('uibutton', $.ui.button);
    </script>
    <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.7 -->
    <script src="~/Content/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Morris.js charts -->
    <script src="~/Content/bower_components/raphael/raphael.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Content/bower_components/morris.js/morris.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Sparkline -->
    <script src="~/Content/bower_components/jquery-sparkline/dist/jquery.sparkline.min.js"></script>
    <!-- jvectormap -->
    <script src="~/plugins/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/plugins/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-world-mill-en.js"></script>
    <!-- jQuery Knob Chart -->
    <script src="~/Content/bower_components/jquery-knob/dist/jquery.knob.min.js"></script>
    <!-- daterangepicker -->
    <script src="~/Content/bower_components/moment/min/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Content/bower_components/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js"></script>
    <!-- datepicker -->
    <script src="~/Content/bower_components/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap WYSIHTML5 -->
    <script src="~/plugins/bootstrap-wysihtml5/bootstrap3-wysihtml5.all.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Slimscroll -->
    <script src="~/Content/bower_components/jquery-slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>
    <!-- FastClick -->
    <script src="~/Content/bower_components/fastclick/lib/fastclick.js"></script>
    <!-- AdminLTE App -->
    <script src="~/dist/js/adminlte.min.js"></script>
    <!-- AdminLTE dashboard demo (This is only for demo purposes) -->
    <script src="~/dist/js/pages/dashboard.js"></script>
    <!-- AdminLTE for demo purposes -->
    <script src="~/dist/js/demo.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Well the problem is that it leaves a big blank space at the top of the page, please see this picture 
[imglayout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EzJqv.png)

as you can see in the picture my layout has a big blank space and the top of the page, how can i fix that? i want to remove that blank space and make the layout fix all the screen completely , thanks in advance

Comment: Without direct access to it, it'll be basically impossible for us to give you an answer.  Use the chrome developer tools to inspect the blank space to determine what is causing it.

Comment: hi I did it but chrome does not detect any element for that blank space, thanks anyways

Answer (score 5):

I solved it by adding `style="padding-top:unset; padding-bottom:unset"` in the body tag =)

```
<body id="elementoboy" runat="server" style="padding-top:unset; padding-bottom:unset"  class="hold-transition skin-blue sidebar-mini">
```

Comment: Just so you know this too: exactly those three meta tags which you are showing should be always the first elements in the head tag (in the same order as in your code) AND without any other tags, comments, code before or between them.

Comment: I had the same problem using VS 2017 MVC 5 Bootstrap 4.1.1 with <nav class="navbar bg-dark navbar-dark navbar-expand-sm"> as first line after body tag and your solution also works for me now.

Comment: I had the same problem using VS 2019 MVC 5 Bootstrap 4.1.1 with  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light"> as the first line after the body tag and this solution did NOT work. I use style="margin-top:-65px;". Hope this helps someone.